# Set default printer in UWP app

Tags: uwp

How do I change the default printer in my uwp app?

```
Configuration myConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're talking about printing from UWP app, the Print Preview UI must be shown to guide user complete the printing operation. When we use [ShowPrintUIAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.printing.printmanager.showprintuiasync.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to initiates the user interface for printing content, it actually handled by system, we can only access the settings for printing if they are exposed to us.

   Now you can refer to the [StandardPrintTaskOptions class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226475), there is no such properties which can be set to changed the default printer, which means, it is not allowed to configure the printer device when you want to print from your app.
2. If you want to configure some user settings for your computer like in WPF, UWP apps are working in sandbox and based on COM, many Win32 API like [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) are not supported in UWP, and there is no equivalent to this API in UWP, so sorry to say that it is not possible to change the default printer in your UWP app for now.

Comment: @焦懐平, you're welcome, then is this an acceptable answer?